# SQL create assembly without access to disc drive

Tags: sql-server, clr, .net-assembly

Is it possible to create assembly without access to C: drive on server? Suppose have got access to database only.

Is it possible to create assembly from a variable string where we could store DLL file?

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY MyAssembly FROM @variable_containing_dll 
  WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found it. On the server where the assembly is installed right-click on the assembly, create it and here you are. You get there `CREATE ASSEMBLY` with the bits ready to move anywhere without DLL file.

[image: assembly]

Answer (score 0):

The FROM clause can specify a binary literal or a varbinary(MAX) variable containing the assembly bits. SSDT uses a binary literal for assembly deployment rather than a DLL.